# Need Help For Validation Engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validation-engine

I am using jQuery validation engine on a Textbox for Validation. When a user clicks submit without actually submitting data, an error shows up. The problem is that if a user accidently clicks on that textbox and then clicks on any other place on the site an error shows and remains showing until the users refreshs the page. I am using ASP.net MVC 3.

Can anyone show me the way to let the error disappear after 10 seconds?

Comment: can you post some code so we can see how you're currently implementing it?  To make something disappear after 10 seconds, you would probably want to create a setTimeout or setInterval.

Answer (score 1):

i didnt understand your problem much but you can do this

```
jQuery('.text-box').bind('blur',function(){
          var e=$(this);
          window.setTimeout(function(){
                e.closest('.field-validation-error').hide();
          },10000);
});
```

Comment: explain ur problem a bit more!!